# where is the documentation of boost/archive?

Tags: boost

I was searching for the documentation of `boost/archive/`. Does it exists?

Esp., I'm interested in `boost/archive/iterators/binary_from_base64.hpp` and `boost/archive/iterators/transform_width.hpp`.

Answer (score 0):

Boost Archive contains the underlying backends for Boost Serialization.

Consequently, the documentation is there: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

- Archive Concepts http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html
- Archive Models http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Comment: Hm ok, I found that site already, but I wasn't sure because I didn't found anything specifically about `binary_from_base64` or `transform_width`. Where is the documentation about those classes?